# InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe' --> works for first loop but not for the later

Tags: angular

I have Ionic (3.9.x) app using the firebase backend and also AngularFire latest .

In my template I have this piece of code

```
<div *ngIf="phone | async">
    <ion-list *ngFor="let ph of phone | async">
       <ion-item-sliding>
                <button ion-item (click)="phClick(ph)" >
                    <ion-icon name="call" item-start></ion-icon>
                  {{ph.type}}: {{ph.value }}
                </button>
                <ion-item-options>
                  <button ion-button color="danger" (tap)="delete(ph)" >
                    <ion-icon name="delete"></ion-icon>
                  </button>
                 </ion-item-options>
              </ion-item-sliding>
      </ion-list>
    </div>
      <button ion-button clear (tap)="phClick(ph=null)" >
          Add More Phone...
        </button>

    <div *ngIf="email | async">
  <ion-list *ngFor="let em of email | async">
      <ion-item-sliding>
            <button ion-item (click)="emClick(em)" >
                <ion-icon name="mail" item-start></ion-icon>
              {{em.type}}: {{em.value }}
            </button>
            <ion-item-options>
              <button ion-button color="danger" (tap)="delete(em)" >
                <ion-icon name="delete"></ion-icon>
              </button>
             </ion-item-options>
          </ion-item-sliding>
  </ion-list>
  </div>
  <button ion-button clear (tap)="emClick(em=null)" >
      Add More Email..
    </button>

    <div *ngIf="website | async">
    <ion-list *ngFor="let web of website | async">
        <ion-item-sliding>
            <button ion-item (click)="webClick(web)" >
                <ion-icon name="link" item-start></ion-icon>
              {{web.type}}: {{web.value }}
            </button>
            <ion-item-options>
              <button ion-button color="danger" (tap)="delete(web)" >
                <ion-icon name="delete"></ion-icon>
              </button>
             </ion-item-options>
          </ion-item-sliding>
  </ion-list>
</div>
```

The console error does not show for the first phone or the phone list, but shows for the next two lists of email and website

In my component I have the following in my Oninit

```
ngOnInit(){
if (this.user){

this.email = this.fs.colWithIds$(`users/${this.user.uid}/email`);
this.phone = this.fs.colWithIds$(`users/${this.user.uid}/phnumbers`);
this.website = this.fs.colWithIds$(`users/${this.user.uid}/website`)
} 
}
```

My service which fetches data returns an Array of observable like this

```
colWithIds$<T>(ref: CollectionPredicate<T>, queryFn?): Observable<any[]> {
      return this.col(ref, queryFn).snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
      return actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data();
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      });
    });
  }
```

And my declarations of the variables in the component class is simple non typed

```
export class myPage implements OnInit {

  email;
  phone;
  website;
```

why does the error show only for email and website and not for phone? What am I missing here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for people trying to help me out. I found the error and it was really strange ..
Somewhere in the template on the top I had

```
<ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.email" name="email" #email="ngModel" required></ion-input>
```

I think since the name was email and later i was using ngfor on email field it was clashing. I changed the ngFor to em of emdata and things started to work :)\